# PutApprovalResult issue with result struct

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-go-v2

I have this lambda go code, which approves a code deploy manual action step at a certain stage.

If the preview stage was successful then lambda will auto-approve the action. If not, then someone will have to check and do it manually. As a starting point, I wrote this code to always auto-approve, before adding more complex logic.

I'm having a hard time with something so simple as entering [PutApprovalResult documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/codepipeline@v1.13.19#PutApprovalResultInput)
and [ApprovalResult documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/codepipeline@v1.13.19/types#ApprovalResult).
Been looking everywhere for examples but nothing. Can someone give me a hand here, please?

My code:

```
func auto_approve(pipeName, stageName, actionName, token string){

    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), config.WithRegion("eu-central-1"))

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    client := codepipeline.NewFromConfig(cfg)

    //approve := { Status: "Approved", Summary: "Approved by lambda" }

    client.PutApprovalResult(context.TODO(), &codepipeline.PutApprovalResultInput{
        ActionName: &actionName,
        StageName: &stageName,
        PipelineName: &pipeName,
        Token: &token,
        Result: { Status: "Approved", Summary: "Approved by lambda"}, \\Here is the problem
    })

    return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK after a LOT of trial and error and reading the actual main source code and not the document I was able to figure out I need to add types. As well…

```
 Result: &types.ApprovalResult{ Status: "Approved", Summary: &summsg },
```

Furthermore, the Summary part needs to point out to a string… If someone can comment and explain why, so I learn something, will be nice. :)